# Put attrs directive in the template. AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the next code:

```
appForm.directive('inputRadio', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs){

        },
        compile: function(elem, attrs){
            return {
                pre: function preLink( scope, elem, attrs ) {

                },
                post: function postLink( scope, elem, attrs ) {

                }
            }
        },
        template: '' +
        '<div class="radio">' +
        '<label class="required"><input type="radio" id="attrs.twigId" name="attrs.twigName" ng-model="optionMultipleChoice" ng-required="required" value="attrs.twigValue" >attrs.twigLabel</label> ' +
        '</div>'
    }
});
```

I want to put the attributes that have the variable " attrs " directly into the template , for example id = " attrs.twigid " . Not very well how to do it and if you do it in the compile or link ...

Thank you !

Edit:

```
appForm.directive('inputRadio', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs){

        },
        compile: function(elem, attrs){
            return {
                pre: function preLink( scope, elem, attrs ) {
                    scope.varstwig = attrs;
                },
                post: function postLink( scope, elem, attrs ) {

                }
            }
        },
        template: '' +
        '<div class="radio">' +
        '<label class="required"><input type="radio" id="[[ varstwig.twigid ]]" name="[[ varstwig.twigname ]]" ng-model="optionMultipleChoice" ng-required="required" value="[[ varstwig.twigvalue ]]" >[[ varstwig.twiglabel ]]</label> ' +
        '</div>'
    }
});
```

This code works , but it has a bug, if several directives instances the "scope" will overwrite , so that all directives have the same values.

Does anyone know to fix this?

The call as follows :

```
{% block _test_optionsExpanded_widget %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label required">Options expanded</label>
        <div id="test_optionsExpanded">
            {% for option in form.children %}
                <input_radio twigId="{{ option.vars.id }}" twigName="{{ option.vars.full_name }}" twigValue="{{ option.vars.value }}" twigLabel="{{ option.vars.label }}" twigShortName="{{ option.vars.name }}"></input_radio>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: the template will only reflect the attributes that is added to a scope. In your link-function, you can say scope.twigId = attrs.twigId, and then refer to just twigId in your template

Comment: I use [[ ]] because i algo use twig.

Comment: I have a problem if  put several directives, the scope will overwrite.

Comment: then you will have to look at isolated scope, look at the answer below then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution .. haha

If I define the variable scope as " @" , it is not overwritten and each directive has the specific values ​​given by twig .

Thanks to all :)

```
appForm.directive('inputRadio', function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                varstwig: '@'
            },
            link: function (scope, elem, attrs){

            },
            compile: function(elem, attrs){
                return {
                    pre: function preLink( scope, elem, attrs ) {
                        scope.varstwig = attrs;
                    },
                    post: function postLink( scope, elem, attrs ) {

                    }
                }
            },
            template: '' +
            '<div class="radio">' +
            '<label class="required"><input type="radio" id="[[ varstwig.twigid ]]" name="[[ varstwig.twigname ]]" ng-model="optionMultipleChoice" ng-required="required" value="[[ varstwig.twigvalue ]]" >[[ varstwig.twiglabel ]]</label> ' +
            '</div>'
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you want to some attributes that you have set in the HTML element. Just isolate the scope.

```
appForm.directive('inputRadio', function(){
    return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
       twigId : "=",
       twigName: "=",
       twigValue: "=",
       twigLabel: "="
    },
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs){

    },
    compile: function(elem, attrs){
        return {
            pre: function preLink( scope, elem, attrs ) {

            },
            post: function postLink( scope, elem, attrs ) {

            }
        }
    },
    template: '' +
    '<div class="radio">' +
    '<label class="required"><input type="radio" id="{{twigId}}" name="{{twigName}}" ng-model="twigValue" ng-required="required" >{{twigLabel}}</label> ' +
    '</div>'
}
});
```

Something like this should work. You probably have to review the parameters of that radio. I am not sure of what you want to do.

Note that "=" in twigValue: "=" and others has a specific meaning.

Use "=" if your attribute is bound to a variable somewhere else in the parent scope, or use "@" if your attribute is just a value.

https://umur.io/angularjs-directives-using-isolated-scope-with-attributes/

Comment: It's not exactly what I want , I modified the post to better understand what I want , sorry.

Comment: I am really not sure what you are trying to do. But you are using a non isolated scope so the scope will be overwritten. Since your variables are static coming from twig, you should probably have a value binding with "@".

Comment: Yes exactly ! Thanks,,,